# Opening a .jar .desktop file duplicates the icon on the favorite bar

Tags: 18.04, java, favorites

This is the code of the .desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=GelAnalyzer
Comment=GelAnalyzer
Path=/softwares/GelAnalyzer2010a/
Exec=java -jar GelAnalyzer.jar
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gel.png
Terminal=false
```

And i placed it on the favorite bar, but everytime i open it, it doesn't open on the fav icon, it opens in a new one, like the image shows:

[All the programs are open and have the green ball on their left, except for the gelanalyzer, which is a .jar file and opens a new windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHOLm.png)

Is that "fixable"? I mean, can it open on it fav icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe adding `StartupWMClass` to your `*.desktop` file should solve your problem...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=GelAnalyzer
Comment=GelAnalyzer
Path=/softwares/GelAnalyzer2010a/
Exec=java -jar GelAnalyzer.jar
Icon=/usr/share/icons/gel.png
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=Main
```

(It's important to have the correct value for `StartupWMClass`; see comments below).

Comment: Didn't work, did a "xprop WM_CLASS" and got WM_CLASS(STRING)="Main", "Main". Changed it to Main and worked. YAY HAHAHAHAH Thanks